# Normal Distribution Calculation having repeated answers and incorrect

Tags: c, math, statistics

I'm writing a program that calculates the value of the normal distribution function given to me here:

[image: Normal Distribution Equation]

The program is supposed to ask the user for the mean **μ** and the Standard Deviation **σ** for the normal distribution showed above. The program then asks for **N** values of **x** and then asks for each value of **x**, one by one. After each value **x** it writes out the corresponding value of the function.

This is my code so far:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

int j;
double u, stddev, N, result, x;

printf("Enter u and stddev for the Normal Distribution:\n");
  scanf("%lf %lf",&u, &stddev);
printf("Enter how many values of x (N) for the Normal Distribution:\n");
  scanf("%lf",&N);

for (j=0; j<N; j++) {

printf("Enter a value for x: \n");
  scanf("%lf",&x);
result = ((1)/(stddev*sqrt(2*M_PI)))*exp(-(1/2)*((x-u)/stddev)*((x-u)/stddev));
printf("%.6lf\n", result);

 }
}
```

I'm basically done but the answers the program is giving me are wrong when compared to my answers from my calculator. For instance, when I make **N** = 3 no matter what I put for the 3 values of **x**, the answer it gives me for each are the same when they shouldn't be.

So I know my issue lies in this line of code:

```
result = ((1)/(stddev*sqrt(2*M_PI)))*exp(-(1/2)*((x-u)/stddev)*((x-u)/stddev));
```

Am I just writing the function wrong in the program? I must be, for it not to work.

Comment: replace `1/2` by 0.5, now `1/2` is converted to 0.

Comment: Aside `double N` should be `int N` and so `scanf("%d", &N);`.

Comment: It'd be nice if SO allowed MathJax, like other Stack Exchange sites do.

Comment: When faced with debugging such a problem, consider breaking the expressions out of the big one, and printing each one separately.  If you'd just printed `double arg = -(1/2)*((x-u)/stddev)*((x-u)/stddev); printf("arg for exp = %e\n", arg);` you'd have been well on the way to noticing `0.000000E+00` each time, which isn't what you expected.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler even some [non-math sites](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions) allow [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: To reinforce the comment from @rafix07 `(1/2)` performs an *integer division*.

Comment: @rafix07 your solution did change my answer, but they are still incorrect and no matter what value I give **x** the function's value is always the same

Comment: @JohnDaniewicz - Can you give a correct input/output for us to test with?

Comment: @Addison **μ** = 2, **σ** = 3, **N** = 1, and **x** = 7 should give the answer of .033159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is clean and functional. Good work so far.

You were correct about which line needed changing - The issue is that using integer division results in an integer, so `1 / 2` results in a value of `0`. This can be remedied by using a single double value: `0.5`, or by dividing using doubles `1.0 / 2.0`.

```
result = ((1)/(stddev*sqrt(2*M_PI)))*exp(-(0.5)*((x-u)/stddev)*((x-u)/stddev));
```

I tested out your code after making these changes [try it online](https://onlinegdb.com/rkx8B26dm), and they match up perfectly with the formula on [wolfram alpha](https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=normal%20distribution%2C%20mean%3D2%2C%20sd%3D3%2C%20x%3D7), as well as what you said in the comments.

For example:

```
μ=2, σ=3, x=7 results in 0.033159
μ=3, σ=7, x=0 results in 0.051991
μ=4, σ=4, x=4 results in 0.099736
```